# List.nub out of scope

Tags: haskell

it says that List.nub out of scope...

```
import Data.List
  main=do
    line <- getLine
    putStrLn (List.nub words line)
```

I don't have any idea about how to overcome this problem.

Comment: You must include a complete code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Not enough informations and you have pasted the wrong line.

Comment: @Jefffrey It's edited.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple issues. It's `Data.List.nub` or simply `nub` after the import, not `List.nub`. You are also not allowed to indent `main` after an import statement.

Also, `nub` does not take a function as its first argument. Right now you are passing it the arguments `words` and `line`. Also, if you had gotten the composition right, it would still be a type error, because you can't `putStrLn` a `[String]`